# Getting from Tromsø to Bodø with buses

Tags: buses, transportation, norway

How to get from Tromsø to Bodø through Narvik with buses? How much does the trip cost and where to find the timetables?

Comment: https://www.rome2rio.com/map/Troms%C3%B8/Bod%C3%B8

Comment: Thanks, I know this, but the fares are not really accurate there. I'm looking for the source of the information on that website and if exists an option to book online.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The national travel guide for Norway is https://entur.no - literally "One trip".

It's available in English as well as Norwegian. It will show who operates the route, and possible changes. Not all different ticketing systems are integrated in the system yet. However, the two public operators are:

- https://www.tromskortet.no/?lang=en_GB
- https://reisnordland.no/

from where you can check prices.

It turns out there's one daily applicable departure, leaving Tromsø at 10:30, arriving 12hrs hours later in Bodø. It includes a one and half hour layover. It'll cost you 457,-

[image]

Comment: One strange thing I noticed. The price from Tromso to Bodo is exactly same as one from Narvik to Bodo. That makes little sense. Are you sure the prices are correct in this system?

Comment: It's the system operated by the transport authority. It's almost certainly correct. The fact that it's the same price is probably that it's the max price.

Comment: In reality there are some helpful discounts. I.e. if you're younger than 30 years old the tickets may cost a lot less.